# Pass Multiple Parameters To Function For Plot

Tags: matlab, math

I have function which takes 2 inputs:

```
function [r] = myfunc(x,y)
```

I want to plot this function but i get this error:

```
>> plot(myfunc, [1 2]);
Error using myfunc (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Comment: That's because you're not calling `plot` properly.  `plot` takes in a set of `x` values and a set of `y` values as the default set of parameters.  The output will produce a figure that plots points.  Can you show what `myfunc` looks like?  Depending on what it looks like, I can suggest options to help you plot your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you're looking for this:

```
[r] = myfunc(x,y)
plot(x, y, r)
```

I'm assuming that `myfunc` takes `x` and `y` as vectors, and returns `r` as a vector. If not, let me know, and I'll post an edit explaining how to properly set up `x`, `y`, and `z` for use with plot.

Comment: This should possibly use `plot3` if it's a 3D curve. That code will plot `(x, y) ` values with `r` as additional properties to the curve... Colour... Markers.

Answer (score 1):

when you have 3 variables (i.e. x,y and r) you cannot use 2D `plot` and you should use `plot3(x,y,myfunc(x,y))` instead.